# How to find email adress of AzureAD user with ps1 script

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

here is the script i use to export the data from AzureAD to csv.

```
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-MsolService

$date = Get-Date -UFormat "%d%m%Y"
$dateInfo = Get-Date
$Results = @()


$Roles = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole 

foreach ($Role in $Roles) {

    $MemberRole = Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $Role.ObjectId  

    foreach ($Membre in $MemberRole ) {

       $InfosUsers =  Get-MsolUser -ObjectId $Membre.ObjectId
       
        $List = New-Object System.Object

        $List | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Compte         -Value $Membre.DisplayName
        $List | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Active         -Value $Membre.AccountEnabled
        $List | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Role           -Value $Role.DisplayName
        $List | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name NumeroTel      -Value $InfosUsers.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails.PhoneNumber
         
        $Results += $List
        }
    }

$Results | Export-Csv path/to/the/file/ -NoTypeInformation  

Disconnect-AzureAD
```

The things is that i would like to get mail adresse from user and i dont know how to do ?

Comment: Check `$InfosUsers.AlternateEmailAddresses`, fallback to `$InfosUsers.UserPrincipalName`

Answer (score 0):

Happy to see you already got your answer, here is one alternative way you can approach to get the email address of Azure AD user.

I did Few changes in your code (ie I have removed Connect-MsolService and replace Get-MsolUser with Get-AzADUser.) and I am able to perform the operation you are trying to do .

```
Connect-AzureAD

$date = Get-Date -UFormat "%d%m%Y"
$dateInfo = Get-Date
$Results = @()


$Roles = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole 

foreach ($Role in $Roles) {

    $MemberRole = Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $Role.ObjectId  

    foreach ($Membre in $MemberRole ) {

       $InfosUsers =  Get-AzADUser -ObjectId $Membre.ObjectId
       
        $List = New-Object System.Object

        $List | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Compte         -Value $Membre.DisplayName
        $List | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Active         -Value $Membre.AccountEnabled
        $List | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Role           -Value $Role.DisplayName
        $List | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name NumeroTel      -Value $InfosUsers.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails.PhoneNumber
        $List | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Email         -Value $Membre.Mail
        $List | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name UPName         -Value $Membre.UserPrincipalName
                                                                         
           
         
        $Results += $List
        }
    }

$Results | Export-Csv /RahulS -NoTypeInformation
```

**Output---**
[image]